# Need help positioning images along with text on overleaf page

Tags: graphics, positioning

Mind if I ask, how do I put my image along with the figure on the red labeled spot of the page and regular text on the right!

[image]

My current code:

```
    \begin{figure*}[t!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]
    {Images/Sketch_hub_verticality.png}
    \captionsetup{width=.5\linewidth}

    \rule{8em}{0.3pt}
\caption{A random text.}
\label{HubVertical}
\end{figure*}
```

I do not wish to text wrap the left side at all!

Any kind of help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please do notshow code in an image, we can not copy and test it ...

Comment: One moment, I will list it soon!

Answer (score 1):

you  can arrange a wide left margin, so the text is offset to the right, then put images in the margin.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\oddsidemargin{6cm}
\addtolength\textwidth{-3cm}
\setlength\marginparwidth{6cm}
\reversemarginpar
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\raggedright

Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.%
\marginpar{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=8cm]{example-image}}
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.

\texttt{\meaning\addpenalty\ \meaning\DeclareTextCompositeCommand}


Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.%
\marginpar{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=10cm]{example-image-a}}
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.

\texttt{\meaning\addpenalty\ \meaning\DeclareTextCompositeCommand}

\end{document}
```